# Creating a Templated Function to Fill a Vector with another depending on Size

Tags: rcpp

Is there a base function in Rcpp that:

1. Fills entirely by a single value if size of a vector is 1.
2. Fills the other vector completely if same length.
3. Fills with an `NA` value if neither Vector are the same length nor a vector is of size 1.

I've written the above criteria as a function below using a `NumericVector` as an example. If there isn't a base function in Rcpp that performs said operations there should be a way to template the function so that given any type of vector (e.g. `numeric`, `character` and so on) the above logic would be able to be executed.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector cppvectorize(NumericVector x,NumericVector y) {

  NumericVector y_out(y.size());

  if(x.size() == 1) {
    for(int i = 0; i < y_out.size(); i++) {
      y_out[i] = x[0];
    }
  } else if(x.size() == y_out.size()) {
    for(int i = 0; i < y_out.size(); i++) {
      y_out[i] = x[i];
    }
  } else {
    for(int i = 0; i < y_out.size(); i++) {
      y_out[i] = NA_REAL;
    }
  }

  return y_out;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the closest you will come to such a function is one of the `rep` variants that Rcpp supports. However, none of the variants match the desired output. Therefore, the only option is to really implement a templated version of your desired function.

To create the templated function, we will first create a routing function that handles the dispatch of [`SEXP` objects](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPs). The rationale behind the routing function is [`SEXP` objects](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPs) are able to be retrieved from and surfaced into *R*  using Rcpp Attributes whereas a templated version is *not*. As a result, we need to specify the [SEXTYPE (used as RTYPE)](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPTYPEs) dispatches that are possible. The `TYPEOF()` macro retrieves the coded number. Using a `switch` statement, we can dispatch this number into the appropriate cases.

After dispatching, we arrive at the templated function. The templated function makes use of the base `Vector` class of Rcpp to simplify the data flow. From here, the notable novelty will be the use of `::traits::get_na<RTYPE>()` to dynamically retrieve the appropriate `NA` value and fill it.

With the plan in place, let's look at the code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// ---- Templated Function

template <int RTYPE>
Vector<RTYPE> vec_helper(const Vector<RTYPE>& x, const Vector<RTYPE>& y) {
  Vector<RTYPE> y_out(y.size());

  if(x.size() == 1){
    y_out.fill(x[0]);
  } else if (x.size() == y.size()) {
    y_out = x;
  } else {
    y_out.fill(::traits::get_na<RTYPE>());
  }

  return y_out;
} 

// ---- Dispatch function

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP cppvectorize(SEXP x, SEXP y) {
  switch (TYPEOF(x)) {
  case INTSXP: return vec_helper<INTSXP>(x, y);
  case REALSXP: return vec_helper<REALSXP>(x, y);
  case STRSXP: return vec_helper<STRSXP>(x, y);
  default: Rcpp::stop("SEXP Type Not Supported."); 
  }
  // Need to return a value even though this will never be triggered
  // to quiet the compiler.
  return R_NilValue;
}
```

---

#### Sample Tests

Here we conduct a few sample tests on each of the supported data

```
# Case 1: x == 1

x = 1:5
y = 2

cppvectorize(x, y)
## [1] NA

# Case 2: x == y

x = letters[1:5]
y = letters[6:10]

cppvectorize(x, y)
## [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

# Case 3: x != y && x > 1

x = 1.5
y = 2.5:6.5

cppvectorize(x, y)

## [1] 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
```

Comment: I seem to recall that we flat out say _somewhere_ that recycling is not implemented at the C++ level, hence the need for an answer like this one.

Comment: @coatless Thanks very much. this works well. but I still have a question when using it in a cycly for a specific task, It seems there must be force the variable to Numericvector. a simple code is as follow:

Comment: sorry, the code format seems bad, I will create a new one.

Comment: @earclimate: Unfortunately, C++ has different rules governing the subset operation. You must save the extracted value as a `NumericVector` object explicitly. Otherwise, you will hit a run time error.

Comment: @coatless Thanks! I see now, I am always thinking with R way.