# Rewriting R's cummin() function using Rcpp and allowing for NAs

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm learning [Rcpp](http://www.rcpp.org/). In this example, I'm attempting to roll my own `cummin()` function like base R's `cummin()`, except I'd like my version to have a `na.rm` argument. This is my attempt

*cummin.cpp*

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector cummin_cpp(NumericVector x, bool narm = false){
  // Given a numeric vector x, returns a vector of the 
  // same length representing the cumulative minimum value
  // if narm = true, NAs will be ignored (The result may 
  // contain NAs if the first values of x are NA.)
  // if narm = false, the resulting vector will return the 
  // cumulative min until the 1st NA value is encountered
  // at which point all subsequent entries will be NA

  if(narm){
    // Ignore NAs
    for(int i = 1; i < x.size(); i++){
      if(NumericVector::is_na(x[i]) | (x[i-1] < x[i])) x[i] = x[i-1];
    }
  } else{
    // Don't ignore NAs
    for(int i = 1; i < x.size(); i++){
      if(NumericVector::is_na(x[i-1]) | NumericVector::is_na(x[i])){
        x[i] = NA_REAL;
      } else if(x[i-1] < x[i]){
        x[i] = x[i-1];
      }
    }
  }

  return x;
}
```

*foo.R*

```r
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("cummin.cpp")

x <- c(3L, 1L, 2L)
cummin(x)  # 3 1 1
cummin_cpp(x)  # 3 1 1

class(cummin(x))  # integer
class(cummin_cpp(x))  # numeric
```

I have a few questions..

1. R's standard variable name is `na.rm`, not `narm` as I've done. However, it seems I can't use a dot in the c++ variable name. Is there a way around this so I can be consistent with R's convention?
2. I don't know ahead of time if the user's input is going to be a numeric vector or an integer vector, so I've used Rcpp's NumericVector type. Unfortunately, if the input is integer, the output is cast to numeric unlike base R's `cummin()` behavior. How do people usually deal with this issue?
3. The line `if(NumericVector::is_na(x[i]) | (x[i-1] < x[i])) x[i] = x[i-1];` seems silly, but I don't know a better way to do this. Suggestions here?

Comment: For (1) typically I think you'd write an R function with the "normal" arguments as a wrapper, and then pass them immediately to your Rcpp function.

Comment: For (2) you will have to role out your own templated approach. Something like this [Initialize a variable with different type based on a switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622918/initialize-a-variable-with-different-type-based-on-a-switch-statement).

Comment: Here is a link with more information to the Rcpp gallery : [Dynamic Wrapping and Recursion with Rcpp](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-wrap-and-recurse/)

Comment: Here is a good one for dealing with `NAs` [Creating a Templated Function to Fill a Vector with another depending on Size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43395996/4408538)

Comment: `na.action` is handled by Base R before passing to subroutines. You need a wrapper for this C routine.

Comment: `na.rm` is not well defined for a cumulative minimum. If the input vector is `c(3,NA,1)`, it's not clear if the output should be `c(3,1)` or `c(3, 3, 1)`, or even `c(3, NA, 1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use this:

```
template<typename T, int RTYPE>
Vector<RTYPE> cummin_cpp2(Vector<RTYPE> x, bool narm){

  Vector<RTYPE> res = clone(x);
  int i = 1, n = res.size();
  T na;

  if(narm){
    // Ignore NAs
    for(; i < n; i++){
      if(ISNAN(res[i]) || (res[i-1] < res[i])) res[i] = res[i-1];
    }
  } else{
    // Do not ignore NAs
    for(; i < n; i++){
      if(ISNAN(res[i-1])) {
        na = res[i-1];
        break;
      } else if(res[i-1] < res[i]){
        res[i] = res[i-1];
      }
    }
    for(; i < n; i++){
      res[i] = na;
    }
  }

  return res;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP cummin_cpp2(SEXP x, bool narm = false) {
  switch (TYPEOF(x)) {
  case INTSXP:  return cummin_cpp2<int, INTSXP>(x, narm);
  case REALSXP: return cummin_cpp2<double, REALSXP>(x, narm);
  default: Rcpp::stop("SEXP Type Not Supported."); 
  }
}
```

Try this on:

```
x <- c(NA, 7, 5, 4, NA, 2, 4)
x2 <- as.integer(x)

cummin_cpp(x, narm = TRUE)
x

cummin_cpp(x2)
x2


x <- c(NA, 7, 5, 4, NA, 2, 4)
x2 <- as.integer(x)
x3 <- replace(x, is.na(x), NaN)

cummin_cpp2(x, narm = TRUE)
x

cummin_cpp2(x2)
x2

cummin_cpp2(x3)
x3
```

Explanation:

1. Joran's advice is good, just wrap that in an R function
2. I use a dispatcher as Joseph Wood suggested
3. Beware that `x` is passed by reference and is modified if of the same type of what you declared (see [these 2 slides](https://privefl.github.io/R-presentation/Rcpp.html#29))
4. You need to handle `NA` as well as `NaN`
5. You can use `||` instead of `|` to evaluate only the first condition if it is true.